# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' in typescript deepclone

Tags: typescript

```
function getType<T>(obj: T): string {
  const str = Reflect.toString.call(obj)
  const map: Record<string, string> = {
    '[object Boolean]': 'boolean',
    '[object Number]': 'number',
    '[object String]': 'string',
    '[object Function]': 'function',
    '[object Array]': 'array',
    '[object Date]': 'date',
    '[object RegExp]': 'regExp',
    '[object Undefined]': 'undefined',
    '[object Null]': 'null',
    '[object Object]': 'object',
    '[object Map]': 'map',
    '[object Set]': 'set',
  }
  if (obj instanceof Element) {
   return 'element'
  }
  return map[str]
}

export default function deepClone<T>(ori: T): T {
  const type = getType(ori)
  if (type === 'array') {
    let copy: T[] = []
    return copyArray(ori, copy) as T
  }
  return ori
}

function copyArray<T, K>(ori: Array<K>): T {
  let copy: K[] = []
  let index, value
  for ([index, value] of ori.entries()) {
    copy[index] = deepClone(value)
  }
  return copy
}
```

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
If you can, please tell me how to implement my deepClone, thank you very much.

Comment: If `ori` is array, why do you `Object.entries(ori)` it? Why not use good old `for (let i = 0; i < ori.length; ++i)`? But practically, your whole `copyArray` is identical to `ori.map(v => deepClone(v))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, if you have the right answer, we will see how the answer is